# Hover text and replace with image

Tags: html, css

I want to replace some text by an image on hover using simple HTML/CSS.

- NO: image appear below text
- NO: text over the image
- NO: image replace with image
- YES: text replace with image

Comment: where your code ?

Comment: How can expect someone to help you without any efforts from you. did you tried anything?You need provide some code that you tried? and ask the question properly

Comment: Please submit some of your efforts during submit your question.

Comment: Please [read in the help center how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: NO: question without code YES: question with code :)

Comment: Sorry Sebastian. Thank you for the help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to start with... you can use css background image, or an img tag inside the a.  I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish, but it's a start.

https://jsfiddle.net/wq2pjafc/1/

html:

```
<a class="fancy">
  <span class="text">text</span>
</a>
```

css:

```
.fancy {
  display: block;
  width: 455px;
  height: 315px;
  background: #eee;
}
.fancy:hover {
  background: url('http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg')
}
.fancy:hover .text {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is! Thank you very much!